# Rigify torso box not working

Tags: animation, rigging, rigify

I've generated my armature with Rigify and it's working brilliantly except the torso box that's only influencing one leg. I'm thinking there's some bones or good parenting missing, but the few parenting attempts I've done got me nowhere.

I see one dotted parenting line going into the side of the box, but I can't recreate this in edit mode it seems.

Any ideas?

[image: Normal]
[image: Torso box moved]

Comment: You will probably need to share your armature for someone to find what it is. You can delete your mesh if you want. You can use[this site](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) to upload your blend. My first guess is parenting or constraint settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. In pose mode select "foot.ik" control bone as shown in my image, and then go to rig main properties menu which is above rig layers thing.

Turn FK/IK slider to the right. Do the same thing for other foot. It should work now.

[image]